# Ascending order c++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble coming with a function defintion for sorting numbers in ascending order and where to begin. Its only three numbers so would i better off doing if statements or an array?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>  //if I wish to use an array

using namespace std;

//Function defintion for sortie goes here 
void sortie(int first, int second, int third)

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter three numbers ";
    int first, second, third;
    cin >> first >> second >> third;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Unsorted: " << first << ", " << second << ", " << third << endl;
    sortie(first, second, third);  //the function is being called here 
    cout << "Sorted:   " << first << ", " << second << ", " << third << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `//if I wish to use an array` you don't need `<array>` to use arrays in C++. Only if you want `std::array<>`s that have value semantic.

Comment: `//Function defintion for sortie goes here` What follows is a function \*declaration\* missing a semicolon.

Comment: You likely want `sortie` to take it's arguments by reference.

Comment: The way `sortie()` is declared now it can't be used to sort anything because it takes copies of the values it shall sort. Changes made to these copies won't reflect on the outside world.

Comment: Why not put the 3 numbers into an `int[3]` array and then [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the array?

Comment: Looking for ideas on "coming [up] with a function defintion for sorting numbers " ?  Did you search for any examples?  Here in SO?  On the world wide web?  (web browsers make it easy).  A sort function declaration is trivial to find ... no need to reinvent the world.  (A little bit different search will even find implementations.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the arguments, so the prototype will be:

```
void sortie(int& first, int& second, int& third);
```

Then just order them with some `swap`s.